# explicit posix mode in dash

Tags: shell, posix, dash-shell

I usually work on CentOS 7 and a standard(?, `/bin/sh` automatically installed) shell handles an option `set -o posix`.

but the option does not work a shell (`/bin/sh`) in Xubuntu.

It says "no such option: posix", when I try `set -o posix`.

What is the alternative option in dash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Red Hat-based distributions, such as CentOS 7, `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to `/bin/bash`. `set -o posix` is a shell option that is used by Bash to limit its behaviour so that it’s (more) POSIX compatible.

With Debian-based distributions, such as Xubuntu, `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to `/bin/dash`. As the tag wiki for [dash-shell](/questions/tagged/dash-shell) states, it’s already POSIX compliant. Hence, there’s no need for an explicit option to change its behaviour.